# 503 service unavailable IIS + localhost + WebAPI + VS Android Emulator .Net Core 2

Tags: c#, android, iis, .net-core-2.0

I don't have any other idea.

I have WebAPI (.NetCore 2) running on my localhost on IIS. When I connect to it using Postman, everything works fine. But when I try to connect from VS Android Emulator I am getting only 503 errors. I think I tried everything.

My settings are:
- WebApi is running on port 8080

[image: Application settings]

My VS Emulator networks settings are:
[image: Emulator network settings]

I am connecting to WebApi using:
    http://169.254.80.80:8080/api/

On localhost (for example from Postman) is:
    http://localhost:8080/api/

I have added Incoming Rule to my windows defender allowing connections for TCP port 8080.

This is my SITES section from applicationhost.

```
<sites>
  <site name="WebSite1" id="1" serverAutoStart="true">
    <application path="/">
      <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="%IIS_SITES_HOME%\WebSite1" />
    </application>
    <bindings>
      <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation=":8080:localhost" />
    </bindings>
  </site>
  <site name="Nerdolando.Boomerang.WebAPI" id="2">
    <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
      <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="D:\projekty\cs\Boomerang\source\webapi\Nerdolando.Boomerang.WebAPI" />
    </application>
    <bindings>
      <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:50628:localhost" />
      <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:50628:169.254.80.80" />
      <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="169.254.80.80:8080" />
      <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:8080:169.254.80.80" />
    </bindings>
  </site>
  <siteDefaults>
    <logFile logFormat="W3C" directory="%IIS_USER_HOME%\Logs" />
    <traceFailedRequestsLogging directory="%IIS_USER_HOME%\TraceLogFiles" enabled="true" maxLogFileSizeKB="1024" />
  </siteDefaults>
  <applicationDefaults applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool" />
  <virtualDirectoryDefaults allowSubDirConfig="true" />
</sites>
```

As you can see, I tried different bindings. And still getting 503 error. What can I do more?

Comment: Are you trying `http://169.254.80.80:8080/api/` from your own computer where the web service is hosted? Do you using a web proxy for normal internet traffic? A 503 is what a proxy would give you if it can't complete the request.

Comment: I am doing it on my local machine. Don't use any proxy. Maybe emulator uses a proxy? How can I check it?

Comment: Is that your public IP? To use your own public IP to connect to your own machine, your router or ISP needs to be setup to loop back the traffic, which it may not.

Comment: No, 169.* is not my public IP. My public IP (on router) is 217.*. My public IP in home net is 192.168.*

Comment: Can you try using `http://169.254.80.80:8080/api/` in Postman? Does it give you 503 there too? If so, is there any body to the message (with an error message)?

Comment: Yes, this is giving me 503 as well. But no additional info. Just "HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your IIS binding is wrong: `http:*:8080:localhost`

You have "localhost" in the 'Host name' field. That means that IIS will only send traffic to that site if "localhost" is used as the domain name. Since you are trying to access by IP, IIS doesn't know which site to send it to and gives you a 503.

Your binding should look like this (leave the 'Host name' blank):

[image]

Comment: OMG! You're GREAT! I've been fighting with this for days and even wanted to give up mobiles! Thank you veeeeery much!

Comment: No problem :) I have fought with bindings before too. I just didn't notice it at first since I don't usually look at the bindings from that view.